# What do you call the type of affection in Bruno Mars - Grenade?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I'd catch a grenade for you
>   Throw my hand on a blade for you
>   I'd jump in front of a train for you
>   You know I'd do anything for you
>   Oh, I would go through all this pain
>   Take a bullet straight through my brain
>   Yes, I would die for you, baby
>
> *Bruno Mars - Grenade*

These lyrics imply some sort of deep affection for the girl in question, but is there a certain term for it?

I'm hesitant to use the word `desperate` because it also implies that he is trying in despair with little hope of success. However, this just seem like deep affection to me.

I'm also hesitant to use `infatuated` because it implies that the affection is short lived, although there is nothing here to indicate such.

Comment: The fact that you've chosen to frame your context as *A is xxxx **for** B* unnecessarily precludes many possibilities (including *infatuated*, since that takes ***with***, not ***for***). But as you so rightly point out, the actual context in no way implies a "short-lived" emotion. How are we supposed to guess what *other* semantic constraints you might have arbitrarily decided you want to impose on the target word, if you don't tell us, and they're not implicit in the cited context?

Comment: What's wrong with _Bruno Mars is **in love with** this girl_ ?

Comment: *desperately/madly in love (with)*

Comment: Have you never heard a songwriter write about an [all-consuming passion](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all-consuming) for the woman of his dreams? Bryan Adams had a soppy song a few years back: [*Yeah, I would fight for you, I'd lie for you,
Walk the wire for you, yeah, I'd die for you*.](https://youtu.be/ZGoWtY_h4xo?t=45s) :)

Comment: Bruno Mars is *completely committed to* this girl.

Comment: Although it doesn’t (or at least, shouldn’t) need it, I’d expand slightly on @J.R. ‘s good suggestion: “Bruno Mars is **truly** in love with this girl.” (adding *truly* would simply permit those who fail to see that ‘being willing to die for’ and ‘being in [true] love with’ go hand-in-hand to continue to use “love” alone to express whatever their less-than-true love for somebody really is)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant that as just an example. I will just remove it from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: [infatuated with, smitten with, in love with, love-struck by, head over heels in love with, hopelessly in love with, obsessed with, passionate about, consumed with desire for, devoted to, doting on, greatly enamoured of, very attracted to, very taken with, charmed by, captivated by, enchanted by, enthralled by, bewitched by, beguiled by, under someone's spell, hypnotized by; bowled over by, swept off one's feet by, struck on, crazy about, mad about, wild about, potty about, nuts about, very keen on, really into...](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/besotted)

Comment: As far as anyone can tell, the type of affection is "all talk and no doing."

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this guy wants to prove his love for a girl by showing her all the different and gruesome and violent ways he'd die for her.

His love for her is "hyperbolic" if not "bombastic" .

Hyperbolic means extremely exaggerated and bombastic means to use inflated words.

But I wouldn't put it past me to add "pathetic" .

Answer (score -2):

Not a single word, but "head over heels" fits well.

Comment: Do you have any reference/research to support your answer? Please elaborate on why you think "head over heels" fits well. Thanks.